# why Broadcom BCM2835 SoC for pi?

Tags: arm

Why did the Raspberry Pi foundation select "BCM 2835" and not any other SOC for Raspberry Pi?
Is any other SOC possible ? If yes , which ?

Comment: maybe ask them directly? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The developers of the Pi had some connection with broadcom. That's why they choose Broadcom.

There are a lot of SoCs that run ARMv6 (like the Pi) and the more recent ARMv7. Also note that a lot of linux distributions are dropping support for ARMv6

Comment: I'd also speculate that the Broadcom chip was genuinely quite cheap. RaspberryPi was never about the most open or the best hardware. Their focus was on a reasonably reliable product that could be got into schools at low cost.